# Customize IdentityUser without Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I´ve started development on a new ASP.NET MVC-App and I want to use ASP.NET Identity 2 for user-management. I want to get rid of the role-thing because I think this is absolutely not needed, especially if I think of the way, ASP.NET Identity handle roles behind the scenes: As claims. (please correct me if I´m wrong here)

I have two information regarding this issue: [This official Microsoft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) points out, that one only needs to implement the features needed, if the out-of-the-box-approach not meet all requirements. The other information is, that one have to derive the custom User from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser`. But IdentityUser implements `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>`

From my perspective, these information are not really compatible, because if I derive from this IdentityUser, I will take all this stuff into my CustomUser-Implementation whether I need it or not.

There is one more thing I wonder about: As I understood the Identity-Architecture, there are mainly two segments: Stores and Managers. The Manager is coupled to the Application and the Store, while the Store is coupled to the Manager and the Storage.

The storage-Interfaces are as flexible as I expected. Maybe I should start here - but I still don´t know, how to create a customUser as an entity, which derives from IdentityUser, without any reference to Roles. Can anyone tell me what my problem is?

The only stackoverflow question I found regarding this issue is 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391302/using-custom-user-instead-of-asp-net-identityuser). But I won´t believe, that this is an approach to follow.

Comment: Can you use ASP.NET Core?

Comment: You want to get rid of the roles, but what do you want in return?

Comment: I don't understand this desire to get rid of something that is not really on your way. If you don't need roles - don't use them. Yes, there will be 2 tables in your DB. So what? These tables will be empty and will hardly take any space (and storage space now is cheap). Trying hard to gut them out will be a waste of time and not very successful.

Comment: @Win: Unfortunately not at the moment. We have to wait, especially for EF Core..

Comment: @Ruard: Claims. Maybe I´ve got something wrong here, but I thought that the claims-based approach can replace the role-based one.

Comment: @trailmax: I don´t have a problem with this implementation. Its just that I was not really sure, if I got something wrong. If that was the case, I would have had implemented something unstable, wrong or badly designed.. To avoid this, I wanted to know if there is something, which I didn´t understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first and foremost, you can't truly get rid of roles. You can choose not to use them, but you're still going to have an AspNetRoles table. There is no way to get rid of that as the role functionality is baked in. Identity is extensible in that you customize and extend the role, but the relationship is not removable. The Microsoft documentation is not wrong, here, per se; it's just perhaps not entirely clear. You don't have to implement any role-based functionality if you don't want to use roles. In other words, you don't have to create functionality to manage roles, assign roles to users, or to verify that users are in particular roles. However, that doesn't mean that the core role functionality ceases to be present in Identity: only that you may simply choose not to use it.

Second, roles are actually kind of needed, at least if you have any desire to have permission-based access controls. If every logged in user can do everything any other logged in user can, then roles are probably not necessary, but if there's any functionality that's specific to a subset of users, then you *need* roles. Also, roles are not claims, though they function much as claims do. Identity has a separate concept of "claims", though.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer! I have an application which requires classic-roles. But isn´t it possible to take the claims-based approach for "roles" too? I´ve read, that it is not recommended to mix both approaches.. And roles are at least less flexible and less costumizable aren´t they?

Comment: Out of the box, they may be less flexible, but you can pretty much bestow whatever powers you like on them with enough effort. Every part of Identity is extensible. Claims are more flexible simply by nature of having no inherent use case. You can use them however you need to use them and mold them to your will. However, I personally think its a bad idea to ignore an existing role system and instead roll your own on the back of claims. Not only do you end up with duplicate functionality, but you're then responsible for all the logic for that.

Comment: This is actually extremely easy to accomplish in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and above. I've included answers over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54162113/608220