# How to remove the role-related tables from ASP.NET Identity Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

With the advice read-elsewhere that Roles are a subset of Claims, I am looking at a clean way to ask the EF Core implementation in ASP.NET Identity not to create role-related tables in the ASP.NET Identity Core 2.0 template in VS 2017. Only claims are needed.
The template uses

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And IdentityDbContext creates these Roles-related tables

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs

How to get rid of them without manipulating the migration files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has always been possible in ASP.NET Identity, but has become easier over time, as conventions have moved away from Roles and towards Rights, Actions, Claims, Predicates, and other more reusable and maintainable semantics. I've been using Identity for years in my ASP.NET projects with my pre-existing DB schemas (which have no role tables). I admit, it's quite difficult to understand how to do this due to the cumbersome complexity of ASP.NET Identity, as well as the fast-paced open-source code changes occurring in ASP.NET coupled with the complete lack of human-informed documentation in the API reference (which is entirely boilerplate machine-generated).

Prior to ASP.NET Core, you could do this by overriding `UserManager` and `UserStore` implementations. By stubbing out the Role requests with no-ops, or overriding the `RoleAttribute` implementation with a more useful and developer-safe one (probably not based on magic strings!), the absence of the Role tables goes unnoticed. Even using the default implementations, if you never used default Role attribute implementations or asked Role questions, the tables could be removed without consequence. None of the default ASP.NET scaffolding depends on roles.

In original ASP.NET Core Identity 1.0/1.1 versions, you did this by implementing `UserStore` without the optional `IUserRoleStore` interface. Information on that can be found in the [main ASP.NET Core Identity documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.0#customize-the-user-store).

As of ASP.NET Core 2.0 (per your main question), you could do this more easily by deriving your context from `IdentityUserContext` instead of `IdentityDbContext`, as per the example below. This no longer required custom implementations in 2.0 due to [the new `UserOnlyStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.useronlystore-2?view=aspnetcore-2.0). The call to `AddIdentity` in Startup.cs also needed to be replaced with [`AddIdentityCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentitycore?view=aspnetcore-2.0). `AddIdentityCore` requires a few extra lines of code if you depend on other standard Authentication features, as by default it does not initialize Cookies or TokenProviders. (As noted below, in 2.1, changes to the boilerplate `Startup` are no longer required.)

It's quite simple to remove roles in ASP.NET Core 2.1/2.2 (current as of this writing). Here's an example using a new project to demonstrate:

1. Create a new project to demonstrate identity, selecting:

   1. ASP.NET Core Web Application project type
   2. Web Application (either type, e.g. MVC)
   3. Change Authentication
   4. Individual User Accounts
   5. Store user accounts in-app
2. Remove Roles from the newly scaffolded Identity project

   1. edit Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs, elevating the context base class above roles

      - from: `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext`
      - to:   `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityUserContext<IdentityUser>`
   2. note that IdentityUserContext requires an IdentityUser generic
   3. due to new Identity code in ASP.NET Core 2.1, that's all that's required
3. Note the `IdentityUserContext` lacks Role, so custom key types only require 2 arguments

   1. in ApplicationDbContext.cs: `IdentityUserContext<IdentityUser<int>, int>`
   2. in Startup.cs, `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<int>>()` is specified as before
   3. The model provided to the _LoginPartial.cshtml is also specified as before. [more details on changing Identity models](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/customize-identity-model.md)
   4. if you've changed identity key type, the default EF Migration process fails

      1. [EF generates non-functional migrations if you've changed keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517422/608220)
      2. simply deleting Data\Migrations works in test, with these caveats:

         - the scaffolded project included indices that are not default
         - if you've already run the project, you'll need to delete the DB
4. Update/build the database schema to reflect the above. In the Package Manager Console:

   1. `Add-Migration RemoveIdentitySchemaRoles`
   2. `Update-Database`
5. Run the app

Comment: That is the best answer I came to. Unfortunatly the AddDefaultIdentity uses the defaultUI which is a pollution. But I cannot come up with a better solution except on creating a new AddIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and it's very likely Identity would cease to function if you did. Like it or not, Identity utilizes roles. You can choose not to take advantage of this functionality, but it's there nevertheless.

That said, in some sense, every authentication artifact is a "claim". However, claims are abstract concepts, whereas something like a role has a concrete implementation. If you need authorization filters, roles are what you should use. You could use claims, but then you just have to reimplement the concept of a role, anyways. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Could you argue more on why claims are abstract concepts? I can still filter with Claims, which can be seen as something concrete. (?) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

Comment: They're abstract because they have no implicit functionality. They're just data. You have to create functionality around that data. For example, you could add a claim indicating that a user is an admin, but then you need some logic to pull out that claim, check the value, and make a decision about the user's status. Roles are just claims with this functionality baked in.

Comment: Do you have some relevant docs that discusses the differences between claims and roles in detail? It seems lacking in in the link provided. Thanks

Comment: Related to this, I want to set a buyer/seller database, if I get you well Roles would be the way to go here.

Comment: I have no documentation to point you to, but this is just basic computer science. Claims are data tokens. In Identity's implementation, it's literally a dictionary or key-value pairs. Roles are quite literally claims with behavior attached, i.e. the value of the claim determines authorization levels.

Comment: Roles could be one way to handle that. In the strictest sense, roles should actually be action-oriented. For example, instead a user having a "Buyer" role, they should really have something like a "can_buy" role. In this scenario, that's not a very meaningful distinction, but when it comes to things like having an "Admin" role, it's a bit of an overreach for  what roles should be.

Comment: Actually, "Roles" are probably not action-based in most semantics; what you are referring to would probably be considered "Rights". It's been one of the common arguments for moving away from the ASP.NET Identity Role implementation, which initially did not support multiple roles, and even today is rather cumbersome to treat as "Rights".

Comment: It's always been possible to remove Role from the Identity implementation by implementing a custom UserManager. Recently consideration for this has been built in more gracefully. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1269

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion by Shannon:

Inherit from DbContext and other related IApplicationDbContext (and remove any other Identity related classes)
will get rid of all the identity related tables. You may want to start the migration from scratch.
public class MyDbContext : DbContext

```
 public MyDbContext (
        DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options,
        AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor) 
        : base(options)
    {


        
    }
```