# How to remove some default identity tables in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to remove some of default identity tables by ignoring them in `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(p => p.HasOne(e=>e.Department).WithOne().IsRequired());
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserToken<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUser<string>>();
    }
}
```

and in startup.cs I configured the identity like:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

When I register a user everything work fine, but when a user tries to login it throws this error:

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUserClaim' because this
>   type is not included in the model for the context

what did I miss in my configurations?

please don't mark it as duplicate because I searched a lot and yet couldn't fine an appropriate solution

Answer (score 2):

I did this in the following  way and it worked for me. I ignored some ASP Identity Tables and also unnecessary column for my scenario from AspNetUser
I am using ASP .Net  Core 2.2

```
public class ApplicationContext: IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityRole>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserToken<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserRole<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()

            .Ignore(c => c.AccessFailedCount)
            .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnabled)
            .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
            .Ignore(c => c.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnd)
            .Ignore(c => c.EmailConfirmed)
            .Ignore(c => c.TwoFactorEnabled)
            .Ignore(c => c.LockoutEnd)
            .Ignore(c => c.AccessFailedCount)
            .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
            .Ignore(c => c.Email)
            .Ignore(c => c.NormalizedEmail)
            .Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumber);



        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");//to change the name of table.

    } }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay! I have taken a deep look onto this issue! Conclusive word is that you cannot delete those tables. If you remove those tables then identity would not work as expected. For more details:

[How to remove the role-related tables from ASP.NET Identity Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910903/5928070)

[Similar issue posted on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5793)

Comment: I have no problem with generating and creating the tables!!! as I said everything works fine except when a user wants to login it throws the mentioned error

Comment: @ElyasEsna Please check my answer! I have updated my answers!

Comment: it's weird, I thinks it was possible in version 2.0!

Comment: Here is an article. This is may be on ASP.NET Core 1.1 but this is insane amount of work. I didn't test it whether it actually works or not.  https://medium.com/@nativoplus/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4